# BSOD when upgrading VHD RAM

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, vhd

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 with native boot inside a VHD. It was running fine with 2 GB of RAM, and I tried to upgrade it to 6 GB. This caused a BSOD, and I haven't been able to fix in unless I remove the RAM.

I've tried several combinations, discarding a possible hardware failure. If I try to put more than 3 GB of RAM, it won't boot.

The host computer is a 32 bit Windows 7 Professional and the computer is a Dell Optiplex 745.

Just to clarify, I'm using a VHD to boot natively into Windows Server.

Any idea?

Comment: Clarify, what are you adding RAM to - the VM, or the physical host?

Comment: Page 15 of the [Optiplex 745 User's guide](ftp://ftp.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_desktop/esuprt_optiplex_desktop/optiplex-745_user%27s%20guide_en-us.pdf) indicates max memory config of 8GB, at 533/667 MHz, or 4GB at 800 MHz, using 256 MB, 512 MB, 1 GB, or 2 GB non-ECC sticks only -- 2-GB 800-MHz memory modules are not 
supported. Also, [Windows 7 Pro 32bit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778(v=vs.85).aspx#physical_memory_limits_windows_7) has a limit of 4GB physical RAM.

Comment: @HopelessN00b I've edited the post for clarification. jscott So according with your data, I shouldn't have any problem with this configuration: 2x2GB (800Mhz).

Comment: @rlbisbe Read the User's Guide again, it specifically states "2-GB 800-MHz memory modules are **not** supported."

Comment: "The host computer is a 32 bit Windows 7 Professional and the computer is a Dell Optiplex 745."

ಠ_ಠ

Comment: @jscott Write it as an answer so I can mark it :). Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Dell Optiplex 745 User's Guide](ftp://ftp.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_desktop/esuprt_optiplex_desktop/optiplex-745_user%27s%20guide_en-us.pdf) has details of the product's configuration.  Of particular interest is page 56, where the memory specifications are detailed:

> Memory Type 533, 667, or 800 MHz DDR2 SDRAM
>
> NOTE: 2-GB 800-MHz memory modules are not supported.
>
> Memory connectors 4
>
> Memory modules supported 256 MB, 512 MB, 1 GB, or 2 GB non-ECC
>
> Minimum memory dual-channel: 512 MB; single-channel: 256 MB
>
> Maximum memory At 533 or 667 MHz: 8 GB At 800 MHz: 4 GB

I would appear that using 2GB 800Mhz modules is explicitly **not** supported.  This would most likely explain the BSOD issues you're having.